# WooCommerce - Output product_attributes list on single-product view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to output the whole proudct-attributes on my own single-product.php. I just got that far, that i can output the attribute-slug of every attribute which is not really what i need. I need to output the name and the options of every attribut. Every help is much appreciated:

```
<?php 
    global $product; 

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        echo $attribute['name'] . ": ";
        $product_attributes = array();
        $product_attributes = explode('|',$attribute['value']);
    }                          
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wc_attribute_label()` function to get `attribute label` and use `get_attribute` to get attribute value. check below code.

```
function custom_woocommerce_single_product_summary(){
    global $product; 
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute ) {    
        $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name );
        $attribute_value = $product->get_attribute( $attribute_name );
        echo $attribute_label . ": ".$attribute_value."</br>";
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and Works.**

[image]